# Messages pending in SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ

Tags: ibm-mq

There are 13 messages pending on `SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ`. What does it means there are messages in this queue and how they can be processed. Can we delete those messages.

```
dis qs(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ)
     6 : dis qs(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ)
AMQ8450: Display queue status details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ)             TYPE(QUEUE)
   CURDEPTH(13)                            IPPROCS(0)
   LGETDATE(2017-09-21)                    LGETTIME(10.22.23)
   LPUTDATE(2017-09-21)                    LPUTTIME(10.22.23)
   MEDIALOG( )                             MONQ(MEDIUM)
   MSGAGE(2986548)                         OPPROCS(0)
   QTIME(15855166, 205244561)              UNCOM(NO)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not delete the messages in this queue.  It is a queue used internally by MQ to hold synchronization data for channels.

The purpose of this and most if not all other `SYSTEM.*` queues is documented in the IBM v7.5 Knowledge Center page "[System and default objects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q081590_.htm)":

> ```
> Table 1. System and default objects: queues
> -----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
> Object name            |  Description
> -----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
> SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ   |  The queue that holds the synchronization data for channels.
> ```

Since the queue is used internally by the MQ product there is no other Knowledge center documentation on the purpose.

A post to the MQSeries Listserv by Paul Clarke titled "[Re: SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ](https://www.mail-archive.com/mqseries@akh-wien.ac.at/msg03932.html)" in 2002 provides some additional details. Note that in 2002 Paul was a MQ Developer working for IBM so the information is credible:

> The SYSTEM.CHANNEL.SYNCQ contains essentially two types of messages,
>   both to do with storing channel status.
>
> 1/ There is a message (possibly two) for each instance of channel that
>   has run and transferred a persistent message to a remote partner.
>   These messages maintain the synchronisation state between the two ends
>   of the channels. If you delete these messages your channel will forget
>   where it got to. This will almost certainly lead to sequence number
>   problems since the channel will start at 1 again and you will have to
>   issue RESET CHANNEL. In the worst case, if the channel was indoubt,
>   you may may also cause messages to be duplicated.
>
> 2/ There may also be a message recording the status of the channel. In
>   other words, whether the channel is STOPPED, RETRYING etc etc. If you
>   delete these messages the worsed that will happen is that when you
>   recycle your Queue Manager a channel will come up inactive rather than
>   STOPPED or RETRYING.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs. In this case it is ok for the queue to have pending messages unless it is full.

Comment: @Rinak In general you should never need to do anything with that queue. I would advise to not do anything unless you are directed to by IBM MQ support via a PMR. The note from Paul above is from 15 years ago. Back then there was some problems with messages for channels not getting cleaned up properly. This has been resolved since. I also found an APAR for v6 of MQ where if more than 1000 messages were on the queue it caused channel start/stop slow downs. None of these should be a problem in recently versions of MQ.

Comment: Really appreciate your inputs